# line break in custom UI element for shiny html is being converted to &lt;br&gt;

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to create some custom html text for a verification process in my Shiny app.

The details of what I am doing before hand isn't relevant. Here is the code:

```
htmltools::HTML(as.character(shiny::div(style=paste0("color: green; font-size:",80,"px"),paste0("Test ","<br>","Test2"))))
```

It is returning this:

```
<div style="color: green; font-size:80px">Test &lt;br&gt;Test2</div>
```

This doesn't work when you render it in HTML, you don't get the line break. It is converting my linebreak (`<br>`) into `&lt;br&gt;`

If I replace `&lt;br&gt;` with `<br>` and run it as a webpage, it loads and works just fine:

```
<div style="color: green; font-size:80px">Test<br>Test2</div>
```

I have tried quite a few searched and other stackoverflow posts that have not helped.

Comment: How about using `shiny::div(HTML(paste0("Test", "<br>", "Test2")), style = paste0("color: green; font-size:", 80, "px"))` instead without wrapping in `as.character()` and `HTML()`?

Comment: Ah life saver. Thank you. Want to put that as an answer and I can accept that for you? It worked perfectly in the rest of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `shiny::div` will treat the `<br>` tag as a character string and will therefore replace the `<` and `>` by the respective HTML entities. To fix that wrap the character string in `HTML()`, i.e. do `HTML(paste0("Test ","<br>","Test2"))`. Moreover, there is no need to wrap the `shiny::div` in `htmltools::HTML(as.character(...))`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::div(HTML(paste0("Test", "<br>", "Test2")),
    style = paste0("color: green; font-size:", 80, "px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7573
```

[image]